# How do you store object references in HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building a form in HTML out of a javascript object that I've imported from a JSON file.
I use a recurisve algorithm to build HTML tables, and respective elements (labels, text boxes, etc.)
The fields load with the value of the current node.

The idea is to edit the values in the textboxes; which in turn updates the javascript object.  When
changes have been made, the editor will send the JSON object to the server and update the file.

The puzzling question, is how do I reference the node that has been changed?  I have tried several 
approaches to no avail.

EDIT:

This is a basic idea of what I'm doing:

```
function build_tree(obj, depth) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[key]) == 'object') {
            print(key + "<input type="text" value='" + obj[key] + "'>");
            build_tree(obj[key], depth + 1);
        } else 
            print(key + "<input type="text" value='" + obj[key] + "'>");
}
```

Now, how do I bind the value of obj[key] to the text boxes, so that when I change the
value it updates the Javascript object?

Comment: Please share code indicating what you have, what's not working and what exactly it should be doing.

Comment: Are you looking for an event that triggers when a key is pressed in the text box? Or do you want someone to click a button to change the values?

Comment: When the page is loaded, it declares a global variable "obj", it builds a tree of elements.  I want when you make a change to the textboxes it changes the global object "obj".

Comment: Johnny look at my answer and let me know if that works for you or not.

Comment: Thats _exactly_ what knockoutjs does.

Comment: you forgot to escape the `"text"` to `\"text\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need a way to individually identify the input so, i would add a `data-key` attribute.

```
function build_tree(obj, depth) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[key]) == 'object') {
            print(key + "<input type="text" value='" + obj[key] + "' data-key= '"+key+"'>");
            build_tree(obj[key], depth + 1);
        } else 
            print(key + "<input type="text" value='" + obj[key] + "' data-key= '"+key+"'>");
}
```

Then i would attach a change event handler to each text input, after the tree is built.

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('change',function(){
   var key = $(this).data('key'); 
   obj[key] = $(this).val(); 
});
```

`obj` would be a global array. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't change the pre-existing object "obj" which I declare when the page loads.  I need to be able to change the object and it's child nodes in order to have a complete object at the end of editing so that i can send it back to the server.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the object ? It might make it easier to understand.

Comment: uhmm.. thats the exact same solution I wrote, before this one was posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('name').changed = true;
```

So now the DOM element has the property 'changed'. You can also use any other value (dates, arrays, etc)

Comment: If an HTML element has an attribute not defined via JS, you may be unable to retrieve its attribute in this fashion without `getAttribute`. However, if you know the attribute was set with JS, this should always work.

Answer (score 1):

An approach I have seen many others use is a special attribute with `data-` prefixed.

For example:

```
<div id="pie" data-like-pie="true">I do like pie.</div>
```

Then, to find the attribute with JavaScript:

```
likesPie = document.getElementByID("pie").getAttribute("data-like-pie");
```

Or with jQuery:

```
likesPie = $("#pie").data("like-pie");
```

As you can see, jQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method automatically prepends `data-` to the front of the attribute.

Comment: Actually in jquery you could just do `$('#pie').data('like-pie')`

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Neat! I didn't know that!

Comment: Umm, how does that allow you to update the original javascript object?

Comment: I don't think anyone has addressed my question at all.  I need to be able to update the global object no matter how far the depth of the current iteration of the tree.

Comment: @JohnnyStarr: Sorry, didn't understand the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html). It has an entire binding engine that updates values between html and object model automatically. So all you need to do is to send back your JSON model whenever the right values has been entered into your textboxes or whatever you use to update your values.

Comment: That might be overkill having to include a whole library just for this, although if the OP does this frequently it is an option.

Comment: You may be right, we can't know, but it still deserves to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This will update your original model (global obj) when the generated textboxes change.

When using your print function:

```
print(key + "<input type="text" value='" + obj[key] + "'>");
```

update it to something like:

```
print(key + "<input type="text" value='" + obj[key] + "' data-object-key='" + key + "' >");
```

And in your JS, if using JQuery you want to listen to all changes on your input elements.
Add a class if necessary.

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function()
{  
    var key = $(this).data("object-key");
    obj[key] = $(this).val();
});
```